# Firebase Functions - waiting for APIs to activate

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I'm trying to set environment keys with the Firebase Cloud Functions, but it doesn't seem to work. All I get is this:

```
$ firebase functions:config:set service.secret="secret"

i  runtimeconfig: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  runtimeconfig: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  runtimeconfig: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  runtimeconfig: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  runtimeconfig: waiting for APIs to activate...
Error: Timed out waiting for APIs to enable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

I'm using

```
"firebase-admin": "5.2.1",
"firebase-functions": "0.6.3"
```

and got the firebase-tools setup. Does anyone know why I'm getting this? Everything worked like two weeks ago

Comment: If this is always happening, run the deploy with `--debug` on the command line and send the entire output to Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson I wrote to them, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Vagrant, and for some reason Vagrant made it impossible to install certain dependencies (e.g. grpc). Instead I just exited Vagrant, installed the latest Firebase SDKs on my Mac OS, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to wait sometime before it activates.